# choosing either simplehandler or executor in netty 4.0

Tags: java, netty

Consider the following server bootstrapping code:

```
ChannelFuture f;
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

try {
    b.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(), new NioEventLoopGroup())
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .localAddress(1234)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .childHandler(new MyChannelInitializer(new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10)));

    f = b.bind().sync();
    f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
}
```

And **MyChannelInitializer.java**:

```
public class MyChannelInitializer  extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    private EventExecutorGroup executorGroup;

    public MyChannelInitializer(EventExecutorGroup _executorGroup) {
        executorGroup = _executorGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

        // and then business logic.
        pipeline.addLast(this.executorGroup, "handler", new MyHandshakeHandler());
    }    
}
```

Now- MyHandshakeHandler() listens for messages, and those messages need to interact with the database.

Before we go further- is the above code the correct way to do this? (namely- the way I used EventExecutorGroup for this blocking type of handler)

Assuming for now that it is correct, here's my question- while it's true that MyHandshakeHandler() needs to interact with the database, this is **only** during the initial negotiation with the client and upon channel close. The rest of the time- namely after handshake is completed and before the channel is closed- all that is needed is to bounce ping/pong/heartbeat/keepalive type messages which do not require the database. Therefore- should that A) be a separate handler (let's call it "MyPingHandler") which is added to the pipeline before MyHandshakeHandler or B) should I just add that logic to MyHandshakeHandler?

If A) how do I stop the message from propagating further so that MyHandshakeHandler is not needlessly called, unless it is specifically the channel close event (i.e. channelInactive())? As a bonus point- it would be nice if MyPingHandler were only added to the pipeline after handshake is complete so that it is not needlessly called as well.

If B) I don't understand the purpose of EventExecutorGroup in this case. These connections are the only type which this server will power.... so it seems strange to me to set a dedicated group of threads which will be used for every single handler rather than just use the default. So if B is the way to go- for this specific case- should I just add the handler to the pipeline normally without EventExecutorGroup (if not- why not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is (A).

To propagate an event to its next handler, you usually call a `ctx.fireXXX()` method.  If you don't call any of them, the event will not be propagated.  So, in your case, you can just swallow event in most case after handshake is complete by *NOT* calling `ctx.fireXXX()` methods.

Also, the pipeline can be dynamically configures.  You can add or remove a handler to/from a pipeline at anytime.  Therefore, you can either remove the handshake handler after handshake is over or add the ping handler after handshake is over (or perhaps both).

Comment: Thanks- quick question though, I believe inbound messages are received via overriding messageReceived(), not an event. So will not calling ctx.fireXXX() still prevent the next handler in the pipeline?